# ASP.NET WebForms Login ReturnURL missing on first time access

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web application written with ASP.NET WebForms. Yes I know its an old technology but this is a legacy project and they won't let me start from scratch.

If the user directly accesses a page without first logging in, the user is redirected to the login screen as is supposed to happen. But, if the application is being accessed for the first time since the browser has been open, the ReturnURL parameter is never added to the login request URL. Consequently, the user is not redirected back to the page he originally tried to access when he logs in. This happens regardless of the browser used.

The web.config file has the following authentication and authorization tags in it.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="180" protection="All" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Comment: Perhaps the first page or that page in question they are hitting does not require a logon, and thus no re-direct prompt should appear?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case.